# How to calculate size of SCNNode in pixels?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have an SCNSphere and I'd like to get its projected size in screen pixels (or more accurately, points).

I thought that this would do it:

```
let bounds = endNode.boundingBox
let projectedMin = renderer.projectPoint(bounds.min)
let projectedMax = renderer.projectPoint(bounds.max)
let sizeInPts = CGSize(width: CGFloat(projectedMax.x - projectedMin.x), height: CGFloat(projectedMax.y - projectedMin.y))
```

However that doesn't work. The width and height in `sizeInPts` is always way off.

Comment: …and it's pretty clear why the above doesn't work. Projecting the _bounds_ with projectPoint is going to be exaggerated when going from world unit coords to screen coords. But still not sure what the right way to do this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should check all vertices of the bounding box.
I didn't test this code, but I hope it works.

```
let (localMin, localMax) = endNode.boundingBox
let min = endNode.convertPosition(localMin, to: nil)
let max = endNode.convertPosition(localMax, to: nil)
let arr = [
    renderer.projectPoint(SCNVector3(min.x, min.y, min.z)),
    renderer.projectPoint(SCNVector3(max.x, min.y, min.z)),
    renderer.projectPoint(SCNVector3(min.x, max.y, min.z)),
    renderer.projectPoint(SCNVector3(max.x, max.y, min.z)),
    renderer.projectPoint(SCNVector3(min.x, min.y, max.z)),
    renderer.projectPoint(SCNVector3(max.x, min.y, max.z)),
    renderer.projectPoint(SCNVector3(min.x, max.y, max.z)),
    renderer.projectPoint(SCNVector3(max.x, max.y, max.z))
]
let minX: CGFloat = arr.reduce(CGFloat.infinity, { $0 > $1.x ? $1.x : $0 })
let minY: CGFloat = arr.reduce(CGFloat.infinity, { $0 > $1.y ? $1.y : $0 })
let minZ: CGFloat = arr.reduce(CGFloat.infinity, { $0 > $1.z ? $1.z : $0 })
let maxX: CGFloat = arr.reduce(-CGFloat.infinity, { $0 < $1.x ? $1.x : $0 })
let maxY: CGFloat = arr.reduce(-CGFloat.infinity, { $0 < $1.y ? $1.y : $0 })
let maxZ: CGFloat = arr.reduce(-CGFloat.infinity, { $0 < $1.z ? $1.z : $0 })

let width = maxX - minX
let height = maxY - minY
let depth = maxZ - minZ

let sizeInPts = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
```

I uploaded the Xcode Playground example to [Github](https://github.com/magicien/SceneKitBoundingBoxOnScreen/).

Comment: I think this suffers from the same issue. Imagine the sphere is radius .1m but it's 1m away from the camera so it appears to be about 30pts tall and wide on screen. The _center_ of that sphere projected into screen coordinates will be accurate, but the _bounding box_ of that sphere is still in world coordinates, so when you project the vertices onto screen space you get something very exaggerated as if the camera were 0m from the node.

Comment: It depends on the projection matrix, but if you use the perspective camera (renderer.pointOfView.camera.usesOrthographicProjection == false), the projected bounding box should be smaller when it's far from the camera.

Comment: Or you might choose the different renderer from the view. You can just use SCNView as SCNSceneRenderer (view.projectPoint(...))

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to convert the bounding box to the world space. I added 2 lines to the code. I hope it works.

Comment: That works! For some reason I get some Swift type mismatch errors when running in my project that I don't get when running from the playground. To fix I changed all the `CGFloat`s to `Float` and just coerced back to `CGFloat` in the `CGSize` call.

Comment: @magicien Can you please provide updated code for Swift 5? I am getting error "Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: @yaali I fixed some Swift 5 errors and updated [Playground file at Github](https://github.com/magicien/SceneKitBoundingBoxOnScreen/).